# SQL: select multiple columns based on multiple groups of minimum values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query gives me a single row because `b.id` is pinned.  I would like a query which I can give a group of ids and get the minimum valued row for each of them.

The effect I want is as if I wrapped this query in a loop over a collection of ids and executed the query with each id as `b.id = value` but that will be (tens of?) thousands of queries.

```
select top 1 a.id, b.id, a.time_point, b.time_point
from orientation_momentum a, orientation_momentum b
where a.id = '00820001001' and b.id = '00825001001'
order by calculatedValue() asc
```

This is on sql-server but I would prefer a portable solution if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server ranking function should do the trick.

```
select * from (
select a.id, b.id, a.time_point, b.time_point, 
rank() over (partition by a.id, b.id
order by calculatedValue() asc) ranker
from orientation_momentum a, orientation_momentum b
where a.id = '00820001001' and b.id between 10 and 20
) Z where ranker = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  One note, the columns need to be renamed or there will be errors like `column 'id' specified multiple times for Z`.